# In which directory should I save uploaded files for MERN Stack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, mern

I'm using the Mern stack, but I'm having an issue as to where to save uploaded files. Let me explain.

I have a form that sends over a formdata which includes a `.jpg` image.
On Node/express side, I receive it well. But now I'm stuck.

I'm using `express-fileupload` package which attaches an `mv` function that allows me to store my file in a directory.

In my endpoint, I have this snippet:

```js
const img1= req.files.image1;
const img1Name = img1.name;
img1.mv("NOT-SURE-WHERE-TO-MAKE-MY-DIRECTORY"+img1Name, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({message: 'Could Not mv file'});
    } else {
        return res.status(200).json({message: 'mv done'});
    }
})
```

Where do I create the directory to store the .jpg image?

- Do I create it in the client's src? or client's public?
- Or, do I run the `npm-run-build` command to create my `build` folder and then point my `mv` function to save the file in there?

Comment: Depends, do you want it accessible to the user or not?

Comment: The purpose of the form is to allow users to create a "blog"-like post, which they can add pictures to. When i render the post, i would like the pictures to show up on the post as well. i guess it's ok for it to be accessible to users

Comment: It's not only okay, it has to be accessible in that case. Put it in the public folder along with other static content, like scripts and CSS

Comment: ok so my folder structure for images will be: myProject/client/public/images. Quick silly question because im not making the connection. So When i finally run my build script and have my code in production, how will my 'mv' know where to locate the correct file, since my build folder will be what my page is being based on?

Answer (score 0):

create a static file middleware in node app.js file to public directory then @ public/images

If not try using multer it is much easier to upload Files